# How do I find the version of a gem I cloned from github?

Tags: rubygems, bundler

So I just cloned the "capybara-webkit" gem on github. How do I know what version of the gem I have? There doesn't appear to be any number in the Gemspec determining this, yet when I had bundler install the folder as a github repository it claims that it was attempting to install version 0.12.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid repeating themselves, the gem authors put the version number in a file and reuse it in the .gemspec file with:

```
s.version  = Capybara::Driver::Webkit::VERSION.dup
```

So the version number is located in the file `lib/capybara/driver/webkit/version.rb`.

Comment: Ah, there it. I can't believe I missed that, thanks for your help.